# How to change UICollectionView height on button click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I’m trying to change height of a collectionview and a view when I click a button. But when I click the button the height of the view changes but not the height of the collectionview.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.backView.frame.size.height -= 160
            self.collectionView.frame.size.height -= 160
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options:     .curveEaseOut,
                                       animations:     self.view.layoutIfNeeded, completion: nil)

        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

What can I do to also resize the collectionview?

Comment: Do you have a height constraint for this collection view? if so, you need to change the constant of the constraint, and not the frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used constraints on that collection view, you need to change the constant of the height constraint, and not its frame.
Like this:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
              self.backView.frame.size.height -= 160
              self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = <value>
              self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
```